Ansible AWX v17.0.1 running against EC2 instance -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'
I am trying to run a simple Ansible playbook against an EC2 instance using AWX. My Ansible AWX is version 17.0.1 (running in Docker, not the Kubernetes version). I ran a 'pip3 list | grep six' and it shows it is installed as v1.16.0 (latest).
---
- name: Ping all hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Ping
      ping:

I can run the command fine via the "ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts ping-servers.yml", but when I try to use it in AWX with the proper pem for the EC2 instances, I keep getting the error as seen below.
{
  "ansible_facts": {},
  "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n",
  "failed_modules": {
    "setup": {
      "failed": true,
      "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 37, in invoke_module\r\n    from ansible.module_utils import basic\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_setup_payload_ye2vc_d8/ansible_setup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 173, in <module>\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'\r\n",
      "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.81.10.153 closed.\r\n",
      "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 102, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1718848180.6915529-730-156986994201226/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 37, in invoke_module\r\n    from ansible.module_utils import basic\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_setup_payload_ye2vc_d8/ansible_setup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 173, in <module>\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'\r\n",
      "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
      "rc": 1,
      "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
      }
    }
  },
  "_ansible_verbose_override": true,
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}


As your module seems not found, you should check if your Execution Environment image got the module and, check the collections or modules path to check if modules is installed there or elsewhere, in that case you should update your modules path.
Note : even if short collection name should work, give a try using ansible.builtin.ping to check if error is the same or not.
